# Routing Error Active Admin and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

When trying to access Active Admin dashboard under `http://localhost:3000/admin` I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`. However my path shows the `/admin` path.

```
admin_root_path     GET     /admin(.:format)    admin/dashboard#index
admin_dashboard_path    GET     /admin/dashboard(.:format)  admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_users_path   POST    /admin/users/batch_action(.:format)     admin/users#batch_action
admin_users_path    GET     /admin/users(.:format)  admin/users#index
```

and

```
new_user_session_path   GET     /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
user_session_path   POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**

routes.rb

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your `routes.rb` file looks like? The routes are loaded in the priority from top to bottom, that's why it's important that you place them in correct order.

Generally, ActiveAdmin routes should be loaded after Devise.

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

Try to move `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` route to the very bottom (below standard root to:)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include my routes.rb. Just edited the question

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Getting a syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxErro

Comment: So... there's obviously a syntax error. You should probably fix that first.